# How do I remove OPTIONS requests from Apache's log?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

Anyone know how I can stop Apache from logging this? It has no value, that I can see, and just clutters log in batches.

```
::1 - - [15/Sep/2011:10:26:29 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [15/Sep/2011:10:26:30 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [15/Sep/2011:10:26:31 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [15/Sep/2011:10:26:32 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [15/Sep/2011:10:26:33 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [internal dummy connection](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection). So, you can exclude them from your log with:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "::1" dontlog
```

and add `env=!dontlog` to the end of `CustomLog` directive:

```
CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!dontlog
```

Comment: sry...I need to back up a bit - I'm a complete Apache newbist. Are these two lines to be added to `httpd.conf` or should they be executed from the a shell on the server? Apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: They should be added to `httpd.conf`.